# KVM-Guest only boots single user mode

Tags: boot, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

We have a Vserver Host running on Ubuntu 12.04 with KVM/QEMU and so far guests been running fine with various OS's (Ubuntu 10.04, 12.10, Debian 6,7, CentOS 5,6).

After the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 Server (which works just fine, via PXE), the guest freezes during booting with a black screen before the Ubuntu loading logo appears.

When putting in wrong network settings, the Ubuntu loading logo appears but the system freezes after "Waiting 60 more seconds for network".

Replacing `quiet splash $vt_handoff` boot parameters with `single` help the system boot up and after entering the root password, ssh can be started and the server can be accessed via ssh.

Just removing `quiet splash $vt_handoff`, the last message shown is "Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [OK]"

I just cannot find any clue in the logs, as somehow no logs are generated on a normal startup with freeze, only on startup with "single".

I also tried to add boot parameters `debug verbose plymouth:debug` to no avail.

This is the xml config for the Ubuntu 14.04 guest:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='254'>
  <name>name</name>
  <uuid>cb6cb7e9-4399-603e-56ce-887f77985bc2</uuid>
  <memory>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <sysinfo type='smbios'>
    <system>
      <entry name='manufacturer'>Name</entry>
    </system>
  </sysinfo>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-0.14'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='network'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bios useserial='yes'/>
    <smbios mode='sysinfo'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/volumes/name'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='ab:cd:ef:ab:cd:ef'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet14'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/31'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/32'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/32'/>
      <target type='virtio' port='0'/>
      <alias name='console0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5914' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='de'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='65536' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Since it's a server install, no GUI is installed so no display manager is installed also.

So it seems that this is a problem of a combination of the used kernel and the shipped kvm/qemu version.

I set up a new server to play around and this is what I found out:

```
| Host      | Host Kernel   | Guest     | Guest Kernel  | Result                                |
| 12.04.4   | 3.2           | 12.04.4   | 3.2           | OK                                    |
| 12.04.4   | 3.11          | 12.04.4   | 3.11          | Guest freeze, unreachable             |
| 12.04.4   | 3.13          | 12.04.4   | 3.11          | Console/VGA freeze / Guest reachable  |
| 12.04.4   | 3.13          | 12.04.4   | 3.13          | Console/VGA freeze / Guest reachable  |
| 12.04.4   | 3.2           | 14.04     | 3.13          | Guest freeze, unreachable             |
| 14.04     | 3.13          | 12.04.4   | 3.11          | OK                                    |
| 14.04     | 3.13          | 14.04     | 3.13          | OK                                    |
```

The KVM/libvirt version used was the most current from the specific repository.

Comment: Can you try removing `quite spash` altogether and see if ti works?

Comment: @Jobin As I wrote already initially, this does not help any other than showing the last boot log message that ended OK: Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [OK] but it does not show the next action that causes the freezes